# error in creating a new xml file in android "eclipse"

Tags: android, eclipse, windows

i'm trying to create a new xml file in android "eclipse"!!
bot there is an error : 
Error in an XML file: aborting build.
and there is no code in that file !
why is that happening ? and how can i solve this problem ? 
help plzzz ?

Comment: have selected "New Adroid xml file" ? That´s important, because there is a option where You can create a blank xml file. Maybe You have selected the blank one..

Comment: yess i think that i chose the blank one .. 
thanks for your note ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is precisely **because** there is no code in that file.  To solve it, put some valid XML in the file.

Comment: but i follow a tutorial and when the teacher created a new one ..
the code was created automatically with it ?

Comment: Yes, but you need some valid XML in the file, otherwise Eclipse will complain. Surely you're creating the new file for a reason, so want to put some content in it. Do that and the error will disappear.